# I saved my model but pieces vanished?

Tags: mesh

So I've made a map for an upcoming video game and finished it and saved, then closed the program to import it in Unity. I noticed some of the faces are facing the wrong way, so I open up blender again, only to find some of my work missing from the map.

I went back through the auto saves, recover last session, checked all my files and I'm really confused as I know I saved it and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue before.

Basically the missing pieces are the bottom of a cave and part of a bridge structure and again I know I saved it before closing the program and recovery hasn't worked, so I would really like to know if this is a common issue and how to fix it.

Also due to copyright I cannot upload the blender file or share images.

Comment: I respect the intellectual property issues, but without the ~.blend file or images you say you're not permitted to share,  I have no clue as to what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

This might be that you have hidden some faces when editing and not realizing it. I can only suggest to go through your Blend.File and go unhide any objects.  See if that works for ya.

Comment: Cheers I'll try it out :)

Comment: If this helped you out please tick the arrow to signify that this Question has been answered.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, so I had to redo the work on the game map :(